# my php file take more than five minute to start running

Tags: php, cpanel

i just made a script for insert query to mysql database
and inside the script there is

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
```

that's script called might 50,000 times

now my website just loading no thing shown there inside
i just made simple script for check the problem

when i open any file not php its  run directly 
and then i made simple php file with

```
 <?php
 echo "Hi";
 ?>
```

and the script executed directly

but when i use the index.php that's contain

```
  <?php
   session_start();
   .....
   ...
  ?>
```

its take more than 5 minute to run the file or to start loading the page

so now i find the problem and its

`session_start()`

but how to fix it ?

Comment: how is it being executed? it should only run as many times as it's called.

Comment: @treyBake yes i just called that's file more than 50,000 with simple javascript code refresh after page finish loading so its like loop till i close the page on browser

Comment: this is because you were not destroying sessions, you need to empty your session files directory or wait for a cleanup script to do it for you

Comment: @FlashThunder can i do thats from cpanel ? or must i contact the manger for this ?

Comment: I doubt that you could do it from cpanel

Comment: @dailytube you can do https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: @treyBake that won't delete the other session files, only the current session one

Comment: @FlashThunder true, but it will start helping in the future.

Comment: @treyBake yes i forgot to destroy the session ,, how long time its need to clean by it self ? by the clean script of Course

Comment: @dailytube do you know where your sessions are stored on the server? Usually, I think they're under /var/lib/php

Comment: @treyBake i thing only the manger of server can   access this i don't have any permission .. any way i will wait for one day if i got same error i will contact manger for clean it thank you guys :)

Comment: Then you just need to contact your host and ask for them to remove your sites session files :) and np^^